# What does 'tableName.column like '?*'' represent Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Something like

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column LIKE '?*'`

What does that mean?

Comment: https://www.techonthenet.com/access/queries/like.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question mark `?` character will only search for a single character, and asterisk `*` character will search for all characters. 
This combination will search for `table.column` containing atleast 1 character.